# Windows Mobile IE 10 not opening links in new tabs

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10

Windows Mobile IE 10 not opening links in new tabs

target="_blank" or 
window.open('URL', "_blank"); ----> not working.

Any solutions ???

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use JS for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<a href="<!-- YOUR LINK -->" rel="external">LINK NAME</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a[rel=external]').attr('target','_blank');
</script>
```